# CloudCraze - Not able to place order using API

Tags: api, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze

We are looking for standard/custom API place multiple order line items for the same product on the basis of different delivery/request dates. So far we have found CartItemGroup is the kind of relative approach to handling multiline order placement and trying through CartItemGroup and Order standard API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Line-Level-Independence (LLI) to adjust the standard checkout flow and:

- Create multiple shipping groups for an order.
- Override shipping address, shipping method, shipping charge, and **delivery date on a line item basis**.
- Split line items of the same SKU into multiple line items. For example, you can split a quantity of 40 items of SKU123 into two line items, each with a quantity of 20.
- Combine line items of the same SKU into a single line item. For example, you can combine the split items in the example above back into a single line item.

https://cloudcraze.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/B2BDOCS411/pages/978782068/Line-Level-Independence